# How can I move View from Y position to another Y

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a button and I want to make an animation of going down. I made it but the functionality is left at the previous position(like the button moves but if I click on it, it doesn't work, but if I click its previous position it will work)

`Animation logbtn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.logbtnanim);`
`button.startAnimation(logbtn);`

And the animation code is this.
P.S. Parent is the constraint layout.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

Comment: why not use the animate method of the view class? Are you working in android Studio?

Comment: Hello! There is a great article described simple animations. Please check it: https://medium.com/@yasmineayad/simple-animation-in-android-acfd26e46998.

Comment: @MehranBehbahani Can you explain more detailed please?

Comment: the accepted answer is exactly what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you don't need the AnimatorSet Tag if you only have one animation. This is used if you want to play multiple animations together.

Second you are using [TranslateAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation) which does not animate the Buttons property, it only moves the pixels on the screen, so after the animation, Android still thinks the view is at the old position, that is why it is still clickable there.

I suggest doing it in Java code using [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator) something like :

```
button.animate().translationY(...f).duration(1000);
```

Or [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator) which is a little more flexible since you can also do it in xml.

Comment: Thank you very much its exactly that what I need.